# Integrating Spring MVC with existing application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to integrate Spring MVC with my existing application. Existing application has context root as `PORTAL` here is my Spring MVC setting in `web.xml` is

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Everything works fine and I am able to access pages through Spring MVC. Pages get data from `Controller` but pages doesn't load the css, img and js files.
Application Folder structure is

```
src
webapps
 -css
 -img
 -js
 -WEB-INF
  --jsp
```

**JSP**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/poc.css"/>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

**Error**

```
    No mapping found for HTTP request 
with URI [/PORTAL/css/bootstrap.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Spring MVC works on URL Pattern and every request for Image and Resources came from client is separate request, So Spring is finding the matching pattern for "/bootstrap.css" to identify is there anything to serve against this Pattern.

And there is no resource mapped against this that is why you are getting this error.

You can say Spring that these are my resources and don't go for any mapping finding, if request comes with mentioned URL.

put below line in spring-servlet.xml file.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/PORTAL/css/" location="/PORTAL/css/" cache-period="0" />
```

this will help you to get rid of css loading errors. but problem for js and image still be there,
So try to keep all resources in one resource folder and give mapping like one below,

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" cache-period="0" />
```

Also, import this xsd above in xml file,

```
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `ContextPath` while refering the `js` and `css` files.

Prefix the resource references as mention below

`<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}js/jquery.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem is that you map the SpringDispatcherServlet to everything  ( `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` ).  You could map it to only one type of resource and then let the server serves the other types.   Example :

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then all you css, images, videos, applet jars etc will be served directly by the server while urls finishing with `.htm` will be served by Spring MVC.

If you need, you can also define multiple servlet mapping for the Dispatcher servlet.